# How to verify the JSON result using the Robot Framework RESTinstance library

Tags: robotframework

How to verify the JSON result using the Robot Framework RESTinstance library. I have API response body that have attached through the mail how to verify the result of the response body using RESTinstance library can anyone help regarding this.

```
INFO 
{
    "totalCount": 2,
    "successCount": 2,
    "errorCount": 0,
    "records": [
        {
            "failed": false,
            "identity": {
                "documentNo": "NPR45787",
                "idType": 1,
                "verified": true,
                "ifscCode": "",
                "nameAsPerDoc": "S Raj Kumar",
                "expiryDate": "2021-01-01",
                "verifiedDate": "2019-02-01",
                "employee": 1,
                "id": 1179
            },
            "error": null
        },
        {
            "failed": false,
            "identity": {
                "documentNo": "********5413",
                "idType": 2,
                "verified": true,
                "ifscCode": "",
                "nameAsPerDoc": "D Mohan Rao",
                "expiryDate": "2022-02-02",
                "verifiedDate": "2019-02-02",
                "employee": 5,
                "id": 1180
            },
            "error": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you want to verify in the response - the schema/shape, or the actual content? The two tasks are accomplished differently.

Answer (score 0):

Not RESTInstance but we do json validation using the APILibrary in  https://github.com/Accruent/robotframework-zoomba

For APIs it uses the requests library but with some extended methods for making calls easier and validation very simple. You can take a look at the example robot tests for help.